# When is SOQL Polymorphism going to be enabled by default?

Tags: soql, polymorphism

SOQL Polymorphism (SELECT TYPEOF) was introduced in [Winter 13, API version 26](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_winter13_release_notes.pdf) for developer organization.

Is this feature going to be enabled by default for production organizations also sometime in the future? If so - when?

Answer (score 3):

No information regarding when this be made GA. As they documented [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm), you can reach out to them and see if they will enable in your org.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Summer 19 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_api_soql.htm#rn_api_soql), `TYPEOF` is finally going GA!  Time to celebrate!